# Playing live streaming video apart from using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, live-streaming

I have an issue (audio issue) playing live streaming video using MPMoviePlayerController for different reason [My existing query for that related to VideoCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340416/audio-is-not-audible-when-using-videocore)

[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]

My question here is, Is there any other approach that we can use for playing live streaming video apart from using MPMoviePlayerController in iOS? Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: What format is the streaming? m3u8?

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with **AVPlayer**

[Here is the documentation from apple to it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html)

[Here is the example apple provided for it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)

Is not as simple as **MPMoviePlayerController** but it give you more control over it.

Happy coding.